# convert cite keys to lower case

Tags: bibtex, bibdesk

I'd like to convert all cite keys in a large bibtex file to lower case. I tried to modify the "Downcase Titles" apple script in bibdesk, but I can't even get the original script to work. When I select a reference and run the script it returns the apple script error "(null)". Do I need to install any dependencies before I can run that script?

Assuming that I can get 'Downcase Titles' to work, can I just substitute the two instances of `title` with `cite key` in the following line to get it to convert the cite keys then?

`set title of thePub to uncapitalize(title of thePub)`

If there's a different way to convert cite keys in a .bib file, that would be fine too, it doesn't have to be bibdesk, this is a one-off need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `sample.bib` is

```
@inproceedings{Zaaaa,
  title = {zzzz}
  booktitle = {Zzzz zzz }
  author = {foo,bar and ggg}
  date = {2000},
  pages = {13--1},
}

@misc{ABC,
  title = {zzzz}
  booktitle = {Zzzz zzz }
  author = {foo,bar and ggg}
  date = {2000},
  pages = {13--1},
}

@book{Zaabha,
  title = {zzzz}
  booktitle = {Zzzz zzz }
  author = {foo,bar and ggg}
  date = {2000},
  pages = {13--1},
}
```

then the following call to sed on the commandline produces:

```
$ sed  -e 's/\(@[a-zA-Z]*{\)\([^,]*\),/\1\L\2,/'  sample.bib 
@inproceedings{zaaaa,
  title = {zzzz}
  booktitle = {Zzzz zzz }
  author = {foo,bar and ggg}
  date = {2000},
  pages = {13--1},
}

@misc{abc,
  title = {zzzz}
  booktitle = {Zzzz zzz }
  author = {foo,bar and ggg}
  date = {2000},
  pages = {13--1},
}

@book{zaabha,
  title = {zzzz}
  booktitle = {Zzzz zzz }
  author = {foo,bar and ggg}
  date = {2000},
  pages = {13--1},
}
```

The above is using Gnu Sed, you may prefer to use perl to get the same output

```
perl  -pe 's/(@[a-zA-Z0-9:]*{)([^,]*),/$1\L$2,/'  sample.bib
```

---

Note the above just alters the main keys for each entry If there are internal cross references within the bib file you will want to lowercase those as well to keep the bib file being consistent, something like

```
sed -e 's/(\scrossref = )(\{[A-Za-z0-9:]*\})/\1\L\2/' sample.bib
```

Comment: The OP is using a Mac, and the BSD `sed` is kind of crappy. So this unfortunately  doesn't work; it prefixes L to each key.

Comment: @AlanMunn I'm sure gnu sed is available? (or would perl be better?)

Comment: @AlanMunn I suppose I ought to use `texlua` but sed is more fun.

Comment: Most Mac users are unlikely to bother to install GNU sed. So yes, perl would likely be better.

Comment: @AlanMunn or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195572/sed-substitution-grouping-is-appending-in-osx-rather-than-the-expected-sub-in-li

Comment: @AlanMunn perl version supplied

Comment: I installed gnu sed with homebrew: `brew install gnu-sed`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846304/sed-command-error-on-macos-x

thanks all!

Comment: i also needed to convert the crossrefs after: 
`sed -Ei 's/(\scrossref = )(\{[A-Za-z0-9:]*\})/\1\L\2/' bibfile.bib`

Comment: @mchlmchl ah yes I'll add a note to the answer as that will b emore visible than your comment